# What is the difference between Android MutableLiveData vs ObservableList?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I want to understand the difference between MutableLiveData vs ObservableList in Android ViewModel.

```
val questions: MutableLiveData<List<Question>> = MutableLiveData()
val options: ObservableList<Option> = ObservableArrayList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference here is that `ObservableList` is designed for `DataBinding` while `MutableLiveData` for data change observation that is made from `Activity` or `Fragment`, which means that `MutableLiveData` takes into consideration a `LifeCycle` of a component and will not call it if isn't in active state.

You can use `ObservableList` from your code of course, but, for example, it will not hold last passed data, unlike `LiveData`.

Comment: So what if I want LifeCycle awareness but also using databinding?

Comment: I mean that `ObservableList` is used not by you directly (when using databinding) but by generated code, that makes databinding work :) In this case their lifecycle (databinding and view) match and nothing to be aware of.

Comment: Android architecture is the mess of messes – and has only gotten worse over the years. Core Android SDK. Android Support Library. Then Jetpack. Then Android X. Data Binding. Observables. Wait no... ReactiveStreams Observer. Live Data. Java 8 Streams. Room. Repositories. ViewModels. Literally every internal team implementing a different solution to the same broken lack of MVC / controller separation that Core Android has. The answer to your question is that NONE of these work together nicely. Because they were never thought out to begin with. Good luck!